# Python: about sort

Tags: python, sorting

I noticed that the results are different of the two lines. One is a sorted list, while the other is a sorted dictionary. Cant figure out why adding `.item` will give this difference:

```
aa={'a':1,'d':2,'c':3,'b':4}
bb=sorted(aa,key=lambda x:x[0])
print(bb)

#['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

aa={'a':1,'d':2,'c':3,'b':4}
bb=sorted(aa.items(),key=lambda x:x[0])
print(bb)

# [('a', 1), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 2)]
```

Comment: The second one isn't a sorted dictionary, it's just a sorted list of pairs (tuples). (But it is pretty handy if you ever _need_ a sorted dictionary—you can just do `collections.OrderedDict(sorted(aa.items()))`.)

Comment: *neither* are a sorted dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, yes, but he already knew the first one was a sorted list; it's only the second one he mistakenly thought was a sorted dictionary.

Comment: @abarnert sure, yes, I spoke imprecisely.

Answer (score 2):

The first version implicitly sorts the *keys* in the dictionary, and is equivalent to sorting `aa.keys()`. The second version sorts the *items*, that is: a list of tuples of the form `(key, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate on dictionary then you get iterate of keys not (key, value) pair. The `sorted` method takes any object on which we can iterate and hence you're seeing a difference.

You can verify this by prining while iterating on the dict:

```
aa={'a':1,'d':2,'c':3,'b':4}
for key in aa:
   print(key)
for key in aa.keys():
   print(key)
```

All of the above two for loops print same values.

Comment: This is close to a great answer, but it isn't one. The `sort` method only works on `list`. The `sorted` function takes any iterable, not just an iterator. Also, you're calling `iterkeys`, which only exists in Python 2.6 and 2.7 (not 3.x), but using 3.x-style `print`, which is confusing. And you might want to include `aa.values()`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, `items()` method applied to a dictionary returns an iterable collection of tuples `(dictionary_key, dictrionary_value)`. Then the collection is being sorted.

In the first example, a dictionary is automatically casted to an iterable collection of its keys first. (And note: only very first characters of each of them are used for comparinson while sorting, which is probably NOT what you want)